# how to optimize mysql query : counting category and subcategory with single Query from two tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I need help to optimize this MySQL query for better and fast performance.

Here is the [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f1bb/1/0) with Query and table structure.

basically I have two tables

#### tbl_category

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_category` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `parent_category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,      
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_name` (`category_name`,`parent_category_id`),
  KEY `category_parent_id` (`parent_category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- data for table `tbl_auction`
-- 
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| category_id | category_name | parent_category_id | category_status | 
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|           1 | Boats         |               NULL | a               | 
|           2 | Books         |               NULL | a               | 
|           3 | Building      |               NULL | a               | 
|           4 | Cars          |               NULL | a               | 
|           5 | Electrical    |                  3 | a               | 
|           6 | Hardware      |                  3 | a               | 
|           7 | Heating       |                  3 | a               | 
|           8 | Miscellaneous |                  3 | a               | 
|           9 | Plumbing      |                  3 | a               | 
|          10 | Tools         |                  4 | a               | 
|          11 | Lights        |                  4 | a               | 
|          12 | Miscellaneous |                  4 | a               | 
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

#### tbl_auction

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_auction` (
  `auction_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `auction_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL 
   COMMENT 'either store subcategory OR main category if no subcategory',
  `auction_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,     
  PRIMARY KEY (`auction_id`),
  KEY `auction_category` (`auction_category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- data for table `tbl_auction`
--

+------------+------------------+---------------+
| auction_id | auction_category | auction_title | 
+------------+------------------+---------------+-
|          1 |                1 | one           | 
|          2 |                2 | two           | 
|          3 |                5 | five          | 
|          4 |                6 | six           | 
|          5 |                5 | five2         | 
|          6 |                8 | eight         | 
|          7 |               11 | eleven        | 
|          8 |               11 | eleven2       | 
|          9 |               10 | ten           | 
|         10 |                2 | two2          | 
|         11 |               12 | twelve        | 
+------------+------------------+---------------+
```

Now I want to count all auctions category wise as well as if some category have subcategory then sum that auction to main category

I made below query

```
SELECT auction_category AS categoryID, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM `tbl_auction`
      GROUP BY auction_category
UNION ALL
SELECT parent_category_id  AS categoryID, COUNT( * ) AS total
      FROM  `tbl_auction` ta
      INNER JOIN tbl_category tc ON tc.category_id = ta.auction_category
      WHERE parent_category_id IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY parent_category_id
```

although above query returns expected results **But** I think there may be some  optimized way to solve this. kindly guide me and suggest me optimized Query.

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that what you wan't is counting twice an auction: first in its own category and second in its parent one if exists ? And, can you have this case in tbl_auction: (9, 'Gold Toilet') and (3, 'Dream House'). If yes your query is wrong. Else it looks perfect and suitably optimized to me.

Comment: NO. if there is a subcategory of any category then that category can not be choose for eg. `category_id = 3` having subcategory then `3` is not possible to choose when inserting into `tbl_auction` so  `(9, 'Gold Toilet') and (3, 'Dream House').` is not possible anyhow

Comment: I think `UNION` is better the `UNION ALL`

Comment: This difference is really not perceptible. Even if it was, `UNION` removes duplicates, whereas `UNION ALL` doesn't, so I guess `UNION ALL` is more performant. And as the gold-toilet-dream-house case is not possible both give the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's killing performance is the filesort triggered by one of the `GROUP BY`s and/or the `UNION`. You can rewrite the query without `UNION` as:

```
SELECT pcat.category_id, COUNT(*)
  FROM  tbl_category pcat
  LEFT JOIN tbl_category subcat 
    ON subcat.parent_category_id = pcat.category_id 
  INNER JOIN tbl_auction a 
    ON a.auction_category = IFNULL(subcat.category_id,pcat.category_id)
GROUP BY pcat.category_id;
```

This has the same effect (double-counting each auction, once under its subcat, once under the parent cat), and the `EXPLAIN` shows no filesort. If it does when the data get larger, you may try adding the `ORDER BY NULL` trick.

Also if real-time accuracy is not super important but the query is executed frequently consider caching the result.